# nav breaks when clicking on social icons

Tags: jquery, css

I am unable to figure out how to write my script so that when it you click on the list element with either a `#facebook` or `#twitter` ID it will not to do anything. If you click on any of the other items in the nav list the script runs as normal.

Here is a link so you can see what i am talking about. 
[www.travismichael.net/satori-website](http://www.travismichael.net/satori-website/)

when you view the site you will see that when you click on the social icons in the nav the home link disappears and the active status goes away in the rest of the list items in the nav.

Any help would be great thank you:)

Comment: Please add the relevant code parts to your question so that the answers can help other people in the future and won't lose their meaning, when you take down or move your site.

Answer (score 0):

You are referring to a relative path in your links. Use the `http://` protocol and it should be fixed.

Like this:

```
<li id="facebook"><a id="facebook-icon" class="home-color pull-left" href="http://www.twitter.com" target="blank">Facebook</a></li>
<li id="twitter"><a id="twitter-icon" class="home-color pull-right" href="http://www.facebook.com" target="blank">Twitter</a></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#facebook, #twitter
{
  pointer-events:none;
}
```